# Change PCB buttons for push buttons

Tags: pcb, bluetooth, button

I have a Nokia BH-503 bluetooth headset with 4 buttons on the PCB.
[image]

From the buttons side of the PCB, I only see 4 pieces of metal.
[image]

From the other side I see 4 resistor (I think that are resistors).
[image]

I want to wire those buttons to replace it for some push buttons.
[image]

**Is that possible? How can I do that?**
I want to prevent (much as possible) solder wires on resistor if that is the solution.

**The same for the leds (buttons side of the pcb)**

I'm making a frankenstein of headsets and I want to crop little as possible from the new headset

Answer (score 2):

If you remove those silver "domes" (like carving them away with an Xacto knife or equivilant) you will see the PC board contacts that get joined together when you collapse the dome.  THOSE are the contacts that you need to connect to an external switch (of whatever type). You have no assurance that the nodes you need will even appear on the bottom side of the PC board. But you have 100% assurance that they are directly under the domes.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a multimeter? Check the on the PCB from which point to which point the foil switch is making its contacts.

Then check the tact switch. Find from which leg to which leg it is making contacts when the tact is pressed.

Now its just the matter of wiring up the corresponding points on the PCB to the legs of the switch.

Only two legs of the switch is needed, usually from the same side.

Comment: Can you update your answer to explain a bit how to do that? Should I put the multimeter on resistor test mode? I have [this](http://www.federalweb.com.ar/productos/3117.jpg) multimeter.

Comment: @jotapdiez Ohms mode, lowest range is usually a good surrogate for a non-existent continuity function, yes.